# ManyToManyField aren't available in the post_save signal

Tags: python, django, signals

I need to manipulate data from a Django model after its saving, but I also need to access the ManyToManyField.

Here's what I want to do:

```
class Lab(Model):
  institute = ManyToManyField(Institute)

def post_save_lab(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
  if not instance.institute.all():
    # Data processing...

post_save.connect(post_save_lab, sender=Lab)
```

The problem is, instance.institute.all() is always empty at that moment... How can I know if the lab has or has not institute?

I specify that the signal m2m_changed doesn't solve the problem because my data processing must be done if there are NO elements in the ManyToMany relation. Therefor m2m_changed will not be called.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: ForeignKey != ManyToManyField. It is a different type of relation. Probably you shall use m2m-changed signal, as @Hedde suggests

Comment: You are seeing this behavior only when you _create_ `Lab` instance or update also?

Comment: The data processing must be done on update and new object.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *m2m* cannot be saved until model instance is saved. If you are looking for *m2m* instances when object is created `created==True` in post save signal then it will be always empty.

I think you can have handler for [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because the data processing must be done if there was NO m2m changed...

Answer (score -1):

You can override the save method:

```
class Lab(Model):
    institute = ManyToManyField(Institute)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Lab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # ... do something with the many to many
        # example:
        # if self.institute.all().exists():
        #     ...
```

Comment: That won't work. If you try to access the `institute` manager in your example, it will return an empty list since the relation has not yet been created.

Comment: @0sh are you sure? the original `save` method is called first with `super`. It should make the m2m available just like when you save an instance outside of the model class and then add the m2m afterwards

Comment: I agree, that would make sense, but for reasons described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) it doesn't work. Basically the m2m-relation is updated _after_ the `save` method.