# Signal m2m_changed never triggered

Tags: python, django, signals, django-signals, m2m

```
class Lab(Model):
  pass

class School(Model):
  labs = ManyToManyField(Lab, related_name='schools')

def m2m_changed_labs(*args, **kwargs):
  pass

m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_labs, sender=Lab.schools)
```

The `m2m_changed` signal is never triggered, therefore the `m2m_changed_labs` function is never called. I want the `m2m_changed_labs` function to be called each time a school is added to or removed from a lab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `sender=School.labs.through`?

and with your receiver method like this:

```
def m2m_changed_labs(sender, **kwargs):  # notice sender instead of *args
    print "signal received"
```

That's the sender used in the example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed).

Comment: First: `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'` And second is never trigger either.

Comment: @user2282405 could you try with the direct field instead of the related name? The docs clearly state that the sender must be: "the intermediate m2m class".

Comment: This is very strange. It works properly when I add a lab from the shell, but not when I add it from the Django admin interface! oO The signal is only triggered when the lab is added from the shell... Why? And how can I solve that?

Comment: @user2282405 tha'ts another question... and I'm afraid it is a bug ([ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16073)).

Comment: Oh boy... Crap! I really need to get this working. I'm trying to solve this problem since days now! I can't change my Django version so I must find another solution.

Comment: @user2282405 My advise is to forget the m2m_changed signal and go with another method such as a save override. That bug's been open since 1.2. It would have been already fixed if it was easy. :/

Comment: The problem with the Model.save() override is that the m2m relations are not established yet, and I need them for the processing.

Comment: @user2282405 You can add lines after calling the save. I've showed you how in my answer to [this other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539686/manytomanyfield-arent-available-in-the-post-save-signal) question you made.

Comment: I know I can override the Model.save() method, but even, the m2m relations are totally empty un the save() method, and I need them to be full for the processing, as I said.

Comment: @user2282405 sorry I don't get what you mean. If what you need is to prepopulate the many to many then save override works, I often use it for that.
Or use a [custom through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) to represent your relationship and override its save instead.

Comment: Actually I just have to access values of the ManyToMany relations, just after saving. And in the post_save signal the ManyToMany relations are still empty. That's why I've decided to use m2m_changed, because in that signal the ManyToMany relations are available.

Comment: @user2282405 the many yo many is availabe in the save method too... You just need to call super before your processing. For example I use it to maintain a particular value always in the many to many, to simplify my queries.

Comment: Uh, I tried but even after calling super, my m2m relations are empty... :/